# dotnet build not compiling .NET Framework 4.6.1 Application

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core

I am trying to compile a solution using `dotnet build` on command line. This solution unfortunately has projects which target different frameworks. Most of these have been migrated to target .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0.

However due to reasons out of my control the solution still has two project which target .NET Framework 4.6.1.

If I compile the solution in VS2017 then everything is compiled and I see bin and obj folders getting generated.

However using dotnet build on command line to compile the solution leaves the 2 projects targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 untouched. The rest of the projects are compiled fine.

Funny thing is that doing a `dotnet test` in the 2 given project folder actually does generate the bin and obj folders. Just an observation.

Will upgrading the projects to .NET 4.6.2 help?

Comment: Are the project files "old" .csproj files or "SDK" project files?

Comment: @vcsjones They are old style csproj. One of them even has WPF !

Comment: `dotnet` command is exclusive for .NET Core projects. Stick to MSBuild please.

Comment: @LexLi Any ideas how to handle this on build server? Can msbuild be used to compile both .NET core and .NET framework projects? Or is there any way to find if a project is targeting .NET core or .NET framework and then use dotnet or msbuild accordingly.

Comment: MSBuild 15 (part of VS2017) can definitely build all kinds. Install VS2017 on your build server and call MSBuild 15 from the right path, and then you are done.

Comment: Install VS2017 on build server for that? Will install of Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 work?

Comment: I'm not sure what the status is of Build Tools of VS 2017 are, esp for desktop workloads.

Comment: msbuild can build both the older and SDK style proejcts. The VS installer should chain in the .NET Core SDK (currently 2.1.301).

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely because of old-style project format

New sdk format projects has to be used for `dotnet build`

I've reproduced it here https://github.com/oleksabor/verbose-engine